# Solidify with overlapping vertices

Tags: modifiers

I have the following simple "2d" animation of a Pentagon:

[image]

I'm trying to convert it to 3d using the solidify modifier, however, I'm getting very odd behavior right at the end when the vertices overlap:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this issue?  If not, what's the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part you answered your own question. *Solidify* gets confused, when at the end the vertices overlap. I don't know how you animated your mesh, but instead of animating all the way to the point, where vertices overlap, stop a very little bit right before that point, like 0.00001 units away.

Comment: It seems like making the mesh disappear when the face no longer exists would be a logical course of action.  Anyway, if I wanted it to disappear, I'd just have to animate the visibility in that case?

Comment: Since *visibility* is not straight forward to animate, because you'd have to do it via material, just "snap" its position from one frame to another, or set its scale to 1 at one frame and to 0 at the next.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by "snaping" the position frame to frame.  And making it's size 0 seems like it will cause the same issue I have here now. (Also, isn't that kinda hacky?

Comment: At frame 29, set a keyframe for the objects position. At frame 30, move it out of camera focus and set another keyframe. This way, it looks as if the objects snaps or jumps out of the picture. Or you can do the same with its scale. At frame 29: scale 1. At frame 30: scale 0. Thats no hacking.   ;)